# Business trip, but not commercial activity

Tags: meaning, word-request

We have in Polish this very generic term "być w delegacji", literally translated as "to be in a delegation". It is usually translated by dictionaries as a "business trip", however it does not have a nuance of the trip being part of a commercial activity—it might be used by both a for-profit and government/not-for-profit trips.

Can "business trip" be used for a non-commercial, non-entertainment trip? Or maybe there is a more general phrase do describe a job-related trip with no subtext of being money-related?

Comment: A politician might attend a conference on climate change, for example. From his (and his family's) point of view it's a ***business trip***, because he's there to ***work*** as part of his designated occupation ("business" doesn't always have to be about commercial activity / profit).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: that's pretty much a full answer to my question. Could you add it below?

Comment: We also have **on business** (I am here on business) and **on official business** (The senator was there on official business).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A politician might attend a conference on climate change, for example. From his (and his family's) point of view it's a ***business trip***, because he's there to ***work*** as part of his designated occupation ("business" doesn't always have to be about commercial activity / profit).

In the context of something like a *trip*, the key distinction is [***business or pleasure***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22trip%20business%20or%20pleasure%22), not whether the primary purpose is profit-oriented.